# How can I pass a primary key constraint during the spark jdbc write step to mysql db?

Tags: mysql, pyspark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, databricks

We are running spark 3.2.1 on Databricks runtime version 10.4 LTS and are looking to write a dataframe into our mysql (5.7.12) database. I have successfully written data into our db but I have noticed I am not establishing a primary key, a requirement for the table.

I have tried using the `.option("createTableOptions", ...)` to pass in some DDL like :

```sql
"CREATE TABLE db.table_name( 
   col1 varchar(255),
   col2 varchar(255), 
   col3 varchar(255), 
   col4 int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
   col5 varchar(255), 
   col6 timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
   col7 timestamp NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY(col1)) ENGINE=InnoDB;")
```

but it fails with this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o722.save.
: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE table_name (col1 varchar(255),col2 varchar(255' at line 1
```

I also tried passing an ALTER statement, but receive the same SQL syntax error above.

```
 .option("createTableOptions", "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (col1);")
```

Right now, I am having to use the below code, with .option("truncate", "true")to prevent us from overwriting the schema in our database, and I am manually setting the primary key myself in the database

```py
dataframe \
    .write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("truncate", "true") \
    .option("createTableColumnTypes", "col1 VARCHAR(255), col2 VARCHAR(255), col3 VARCHAR(255), col4 INT, col5 VARCHAR(255), col6 TIMESTAMP, col7 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL") \
    .option("url", uri) \
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .save()
```

I am hoping there is a way to achieve what I want in a single step, rather than having to make interactions with the mysql database to establish the constraints i need??